# Qt4 QLabel in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlabel, qtabwidget

I want to dynamically created interface for my hello-world QT + C++ program from .ini file.

1 Step I read settings file with QSettings - it is simple.

2 Step I try to draw interface:

```
//i == 5;
for(int temp=1;temp <= i;temp++){
    QString tName = settings.value("/Level" + QString::number(temp) + "/Name", "").toString();
    QString tImage = settings.value("/Level" + QString::number(temp) + "/Image", "").toString();
    QString Imgpath = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/images/" + tImage;
    QPixmap pix(Imgpath);
    tab.addTab(new QLabel(Imgpath, &tab), tName);
}
```

All looks great - QLabel contains filepath to image, header of TAB contains right NAME from iniFile. BUT! I want to setPixmap() to QLabel and here is problem. `new QLabel()` query doesn't have any name I can use to set any option. Please help me with that for(){}

Comment: "new QLabel() query doesn't have any name I can use to set any option" -- What does this means?

Comment: Are you trying to draw an icon next to tab name, or make a tab widget that shows images in tabs?

Comment: "What does this means?" - I mean that here is no `QLabel lbl();` in this code and I don't know where I can add this to use then `lbl.setPixmap(LinkToPix);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this:

```
QPixmap pix(Imgpath);
tab.addTab(new QLabel(Imgpath, &tab), tName);
```

to:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(Imgpath, &tab);
label->setPixmap(QPixmap(Imgpath));
tab.addTab(label, tName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pixmap property:

> [pixmap : QPixmap](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop)
>
> This property holds the label's pixmap.
>
> If no pixmap has been set this will return 0.
>
> Setting the pixmap clears any previous content. The buddy shortcut, if any, is disabled.

So, you would set your pixmap on the label as follows:

```
//i == 5;
for (int temp = 1; temp <= i; ++temp) {
    QString tName = settings.value("/Level" + QString::number(temp) + "/Name", "").toString();
    QString tImage = settings.value("/Level" + QString::number(temp) + "/Image", "").toString();
    QString Imgpath = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/images/" + tImage;
    QPixmap pix(Imgpath);
    QLabel *myLabel = new QLabel(Imgpath, &tab);
    myLabel->setPixmap(pix);
    tab.addTab(myLabel, tName);
}
```